# Getting all id's of group with recent record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have users with different group code in my MySQL database. I am saving their latitude and longitude in database according to their current positions.

> Problem is I am not able to get their recent records according to their group code.

I have tried this

```
     SELECT * FROM tracklatlong WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX( id ) FROM 
tracklatlong GROUP BY  'track_CfiUw');
```

but i am only getting last record of this track_CfiUw group code.

i want result like below

[image]

[image: I want result like recent records of perticular user according their group]

Comment: you should show your desire output

Comment: I dont know whether its possible or not bt according to recent time

Comment: @SagarGopale   you want all user in this group "track_CfiUw" ?

Comment: @mohade yes without duplications recent record for each user in a group

Comment: @SagarGopale try this  : SELECT * FROM tracklatlong WHERE groupcode='track_CfiUw' GROUP BY admin_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like,

```
 SELECT tl1.id,tl1.admin_id,tl1.name,tl1.groupcode
 FROM tracklatlong tl1 
 LEFT JOIN tracklatlong tl2 ON (tl1.name = tl2.name AND tl1.id < tl2.id)
 WHERE tl2.id IS NULL AND tl1.groupcode = 'track_CfiUw';
```

But instead you are grouping it by `group_code value`.

Comment: I have tried but I am getting only two records of different groups.

Comment: I am getting this error   #1052 - Column 'groupcode' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: Ok I made changes in query, check now